# Unable to remove nodes from linked list except the first node

Tags: python-3.x, linked-list, singly-linked-list

I'm learning the basics of linked lists but I'm having difficulties with removing nodes. When I remove the first node by writing `list1.RemoveNode("Dog")`, the code successfully returns the elements

```
Cat
Mouse
Rabbit
```

But when I do the command `list1.RemoveNode("Cat")`, the code doesn't delete the node value "Cat". Instead, it still prints out all the node values as so:

```
Dog
Cat
Mouse
Rabbit
```

As a matter of fact, the `RemoveNode` function only works on "Dog". I'm not sure what's wrong. I've attached my code below.

```
class Node():
    def __init__(self,dataval=None):
        self.dataval=dataval
        self.nextval=None

class Linkedlist():
    def __init__(self,headval=None):
        self.headval=headval

    def printlist(self):
        headval=self.headval
        while headval is not None:
            print(headval.dataval)
            headval=headval.nextval
 
    def RemoveNode(self, Removekey):
        HeadVal = self.headval
        if (HeadVal is not None):
                if (HeadVal.dataval == Removekey):
                    self.headval = HeadVal.nextval
                    HeadVal = None
                    return

        while (HeadVal is not None):
                if HeadVal.dataval == Removekey:
                    break
                prev = HeadVal
                HeadVal = HeadVal.nextval

        if (HeadVal == None):
            return

        prev.next = HeadVal.nextval

        HeadVal = None


Node1=Node("Dog")
Node2=Node("Cat")
Node3=Node("Mouse")
Node4=Node("Rabbit")           
list1=Linkedlist()
list1.headval=Node1
Node1.nextval=Node2
Node2.nextval=Node3
Node3.nextval=Node4
list1.RemoveNode("Cat")
list1.printlist()
```

Comment: Looks like Python, please add P.L.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line in RemoveNode

```
prev.next = HeadVal.nextval
```

should be

```
prev.nextval = HeadVal.nextval
```